# Ruby on rails, Cómo realizo una petición http con una cookie de sesión

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Usando el método **Net::HTTP** pude realizar una cookie donde se guardan los  datos de inicio de sesión, mi conflicto es que no puedo realizar la petición http e integrarle dicha cookie

```
data = @http.get("#{@path}?nombre=#{@parameters["nombre"]}&paterno=#{@parameters["paterno"]}&materno=#{@parameters["materno"]}", @headers)
```

La cookie quiero añadirla como cabecera CORS en el caso de **@headers** contiene lo siguiente

```
@headers = { 'Cookie' => @cookie }
```

esto me regresa un XML que interpretare mas adelante, por el momento me envia un error

```
<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>
```

El código de cookie lo recibo de la siguiente parte

```
resp, data = http.get("#{path}?".concat(params.collect{ |k, v| "#{k}=#{CGI::escape(v.to_s)}" }.join('&') ))
        cookie = resp.response['set-cookie']
```

Comment: ¿y dónde defines el valor de `@cookie`? de hecho, agrega todo el código relevante. Se me ocurre que no estás recibiendo todas las cookies o no estás agregando todas las que necesitas.

Comment: Agregue la parte que mencionas, y el resultado de la cookie cuando la imprimo es un qkey y un quid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica que la cookie de sesión contenga en qnid aparte de la qkey para que determines si la conexión se establecio correctamente, si  y al pegarla en la cabecera CORS hazlo de la sigueinte manera

```
resp, data = @http.get("#{@path}?".concat(@parameters.collect{ |k, v| "#{k}=#{CGI::escape(v.to_s.downcase)}" }.join('&') ), @headers)
```

De esta manera garantizas la construcción de tu url sin comprometer los datos